# How to cut canvas Data URI links?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, hyperlink

Is some way for cut links from canvas `toDataUrl` method? Or maybe some another way for saving canvas images?

Comment: Are you exceeding some transport protocol's transfer length? If not, don't divide the dataURL into chunks. If yes, the dataURL is just a string so you can String.slice it into allowed-sized chunks. Or you could use some other transport protocol. For example you could convert the canvas content into a blob and transfer that.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use proper terms for whatever it is you're trying to do, because I don't know what "cut links" means, but here are some guesses..

**Create a link that links to the image...**

```
var datauri = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL();
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.innerHTML = "Download image";
link.setAttribute("href", datauri);
document.body.appendChild(link);
```

**Open the image in a new tab**

```
var datauri = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL();
window.open(datauri, "_blank");
```

---

Bonus... these require PHP, and use a library I've written, [EasyImage](http://geneticcoder.com/EasyImage/)

**Download the image to the user's computer**

Create this PHP file on the server, call it downloader.php:

```
<?php
require "EasyImage.php";
EasyImage::Create($_POST['img'])->download("yourImage.png");
```

Then post the dataURI to the PHP script and it will force a download to the user's computer

```
<form href="downloader.php" method="POST" id="dlform"><input type="hidden" id="img" name="img"></form>
<script>
function downloadImage(){
    var datauri = document.getElementById("myCanvas").toDataURL();
    document.getElementById("img").value = datauri;
    document.getElementById("dlform").submit();
}
</script>
```

Then just call `downloadImage()` to download the image

If you want to save the iamge to the server instead you can replace this `->download("yourImage.png");` with `->save("yourImage.png");`

In the future you need to be much, **much** more specific so people don't have to guess, because most people won't guess, they will just move on to the next question...

Comment: I mean dataURL links generated from toDataUrl() method looks like: data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/wAFCviHP8SPgbpviTwLpN3JDZeHdOtore2tZzbRNEy2wKQOm7cGRht+...LpN3JDZeHdOtore2tZzbRNEy2wKQOm7cG, and when i wanna save image to php database i have to use 'longtext' field in phpmyadmin. I just thought about its some another method, when links would look like myImage.jpg